# What yellow import lines mean in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, import

I'm new to android and android studio. I recognized that some import lines are in different color. what does this mean? what is the difference of these lines with other lines?

[image]

Comment: these lines for annotations imports

Comment: Those are imports for annotations, like ```@NonNull/@Nullable/@StringDef/@IntDef```...etc. For more about annotations check http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations

Comment: what was the downvote for?

Comment: @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani see my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means it's an `annotation class import`.

**Java Annotations** allow us to `add metadata information into our source code`, although they are not a part of the program itself. Annotations were added to the java from `JDK 5`. Annotation has no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate (i.e. it does not affect the execution of the program)

### What’s the use of Annotations.

**1) Instructions to the compiler:** There are three built-in annotations available in Java (`@Deprecated`, `@Override` & `@SuppressWarnings`) that can be used for giving certain instructions to the compiler. For example the `@override` annotation is used for instructing compiler that the annotated method is overriding the method. More about these built-in annotations with example is discussed in the next sections of this article.

**2) Compile-time instructors:** Annotations can provide compile-time instructions to the compiler that can be further used by sofware build tools for generating code, XML files etc.

**3) Runtime instructions:** We can define annotations to be available at runtime which we can access using `java reflection` and can be used to give instructions to the program at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

Annotation is type of metadata about program with not being part of it...

> Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on the operation of the code they annotate.
>
> It contains information about :
>
> 1. Information for the compiler
> 2. Compile-time and deployment
> 3. Runtime processing

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/)

In Java8 there are improved Annotation like :

1. **@NonNull**: The compiler can determine cases where a code path might receive a null value, without ever having to debug a NullPointerException.
2. **@ReadOnly**: The compiler will flag any attempt to change the object.  This is similar to Collections.unmodifiableList, but more general and verified at compile time.
3. **@Regex**:  Provides compile-time verification that a String intended to be used as a regular expression is a properly formatted regular expression.
4. **@Tainted and @Untainted**: Identity types of data that should not be used together, such as remote user input being used in system commands, or sensitive information in log streams.
5. **@m**: Units of measure ensures that numbers used for measuring objects are used and compared correctly, or have undergone the proper unit conversion.

[Check document for explanation](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/java_8_s_new_type)

You can also look this beautiful article at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation)

Answer (score 1):

It means it's an annotation class import.

From the javadocs:

> Annotations, a form of metadata, provide data about a program that is
>   not part of the program itself. Annotations have no direct effect on
>   the operation of the code they annotate.

Check out the [developer's guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations.html)  on Annotations.

Also take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/package-summary.html) summary on the available annotations in Android.

Answer (score 1):

When you try to import annotations

like `@StringDef`, `@IntDef`, `@Nullable` or `@NonNull`

at that time these kind of imports will be in yellow color.